# Top of stack trace in Google Play Developer Console is obfuscated

Tags: android, stack

We've uploaded our mapping file to the Google Play Developer console and most of the stack trace is deobfuscated.  However, the top part seems to still be obfuscated in some traces (not all).

Anyone know why this could be and what we could do to fix it?

See `avt.b(int)` in trace below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void avt.b(int)' on a null object reference
at com.ourdomain.ourapp.ui.fragments.rewards.OurFragment.onClicked(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 onReceiveLocalBroadcastIntent(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 removeTrip(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 getMapData(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 notifyDataAvailable(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 onTripDBCallBack(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 access$008(OurFragment.java)
at com.ourdomain.ourapp.ui.fragments.rewards.OurFragment.onClicked(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 onReceiveLocalBroadcastIntent(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 removeTrip(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 getMapData(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 notifyDataAvailable(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 onTripDBCallBack(OurFragment.java)
                                                                 access$008(OurFragment.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload an APK to Alpha with proguard disabled and see the stacktrace.

```
release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

This way you don't upload any APK to production without the code being obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

disable obfuscation in proguard file:

```
-dontobfuscate
```

Comment: We can't do that.  We need stuff to be obfuscated.